# Calculator Algorithm - Using Iteration instead of Recursion on Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I've seen approaches on how to iterate through binary trees and find the sum of all nodes, except I'm evaluating expression inputs for a calculator. The nodes are arranged in the proper order according to order of operations and the nodes are either `operators` or `operands`. I think `recursion` is slower than iteration for this so I wanted to figure out how to go through the binary tree and find the result of the expression inputed without `recursion`.

An example of the tree:

```
      +
  *       /
3   4   4   2
```

The recursive method I have so far (I used an enum for the operator):

```
public static float evaluate(BETNode root)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: Root is null!");
    }

    if (root.getType() == BETNodeType.OPERAND)
    {
        return root.getOperand();
    }

    float leftValue = evaluate(root.getLeft());
    float rightValue = evaluate(root.getRight());

    switch (root.getOperator())
    {
        case '+':
            return leftValue + rightValue;

        case '-':
            return leftValue - rightValue;

        case '*':
            return leftValue * rightValue;

        case '/':
            return leftValue/rightValue;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, if you did an [iterative post-order traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294701/post-order-traversal-of-binary-tree-without-recursion), you'd get nodes in the order:

`3, 4, *, 4, 2, /, +.`

From this, you'd simply need a stack to evaluate the expression.

```
Push 3
Push 4
Push (pop() * pop())

Push 4
Push 2
Push (pop() / pop())
Push (pop() + pop())
//Result
```

Also interesting would be the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) which does the evaluation from an infix expression.